# Directory Listing Denied Message

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, redhat, nic

Understand that this is the common error for a missing index.* in the location being pointed to by Apache, however I know it to be the case that there is an index.php in the location specified as the root directory.

Server Specs:
RHEL 6 with Apache
Multiple sites and virtual IPs on this box (all others working as expected, with seemingly same setup as this one -its a clone of the other just like the 10 others I did right before it)

What I have tried:

- Changing the permissions on that directory (even to 777 for testing)
- Copying files to a new directory and pointing the root folder for
  that site there.
- Confirming its virtual interface card eth0:123456 is setup
  correctly and the apache `httpd.conf` is to use the IP in that
  virtual interface
- Bounced Server, Apache, NIC

Additional Info

- I've tried creating a test folder in /var/www/html/test  with an
  index.html in it and still no luck.

Comment: (1) Check that `DocumentRoot` is set to /var/www/html.  (2) Check that /, /var, and /var/www are also readable and executable by user apache. (3) Set `Loglevel debug`, and check your error log file for details.

Comment: Yea they are i have three other sites in that directory that are working as expected...

Comment: We need the relevant apache config in order to help. Also a relevant entry from the error log.